Non-degenerate bilinear pairing of finite dimensional algebras
A finite dimensional algebra (over $\mathbb{C}$, say) is said to be Frobenius if it comes equipped with a nondegenerate bilinear pairing
\begin{align*}
\langle -, - \rangle : A \times A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}. 
\end{align*}
so that $\langle ab, c \rangle = \langle a, bc \rangle$, which then implies that the algebra is isomorphic to its dual. I'm wondering if there is a more general statement, so that if $A$ and $B$ are algebras of the same dimension and there exists a nondegenerate bilinear pairing
\begin{align*}
\langle -, - \rangle : A \times B^\text{op} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}. 
\end{align*}
that satisfies a similar multiplicativity condition (say we now that $A$ and $B$ are modules over each other, so that the equation $\langle ab, c \rangle = \langle a, bc \rangle$ makes sense), can we conclude that $A \cong B^\text{op}$?

What properties has your pairing w.r.t. multiplication? If it is just bilinear, the only consequence you'll get is $\dim B=\dim A$.

Sorry! Yes it should satisfy a similar multiplicativity condition to the one giving the definition of a Frobenius algebra, I have updated the question with a candidate :) Thanks for pointing this out!

I'm not sure I understand why this would be a more general statement. If $A=B^{op}$ then the hypotheses look the same but the conclusions are different. I'm also not sure what the purpose of the ${}^{op}$ is.
